# How to move and open shapefiles with ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr2ogr, d3

I'm a total newb following along the [d3 map tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/).

at this line:

```
    ogr2ogr \
  -f GeoJSON \
  -where "adm0_a3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')" \
  subunits.json \
  ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
```

I get this output:

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource 'ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> GMT
  -> PCIDSK
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDump
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> EDIGEO
  -> SVG
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
```

This has been [asked before](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45469/how-do-you-open-shapefiles-with-ogr2ogr), but I have ogr2ogr installed correctly, and my question is much more basic.

I haven't moved any .shp, .shx, .dbf, and .prj files. I'm following the tutorial closely, and haven't created any type of project directory, so I am still working out of usr/bin/local. Do I need to move certain files to a new project folder? If so where can I find them?

Comment: So you downloaded the files to /usr/local/bin?

Comment: i'm not sure, I did brew install gdal, how would I figure out where I downloaded the files to?

Comment: In the tutorial I downloaded both folders ne_10m_populated_places and ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits, and I was working out of the folder that had both of the unzipped folders in them. I needed to open ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Didn't 'get it' with the answer below. The key to resolving this error for me was knowing that the rest of the files in that zip folder, besides the shape(.shp) file(!), were important in the process of converting it to GeoJSON format using ogr2ogr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just install ogr2ogr on Ubuntu 12.10.

I then downloaded the files that that tutorial said to download.

I then created a directory in my home directory called d3.

I unzipped the zip files in the d3 directory.

I then navigated to the d3 directory in the terminal.

I then ran the command and it worked.

I then rant he command with a bad file name and recieved the same error as you just did.

This leads me to believe that the ogr2ogr command cannot find the filename you are entering because you do not have that file in the directory you are running the command.  You do not need to run the command from the usr/bin/local directory.  If it will not run in the directory with the data you may need to give the full path before runnning the commnad in the direcotry with the data.  It would look like this:

$usr/local/bin/ogr2ogr \
    -f GeoJSON \
    -where "adm0_a3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')" \
    subunits.json \
    ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp

Comment: so I ran the command with the full path, and it gives me: -bash: /local/bin/ogr2ogr: No such file or directory.

i must have downloaded the files to the wrong directory.

Comment: I downloaded them to the wrong directory. This makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, if this solved your issue, then please mark it as the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

I think ogr is expecting the shapefile to be in whatever the current directory is--are you sure you got to the correct directory before running ogr2ogr?  you can also use [ogrinfo](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html) to check on the file (for ex: ogrinfo -so filename.shp)

Comment: Thank you!  I assumed it would work like any other CLI program and accept a file path. I'm using QGIS on Windows and none of the CLI programs are in my PATH, so I was running them from the QGIS `bin` folder and passing paths to my datasets, and nothing was working. When I switched my directory to where my datasets lived, and used the full path to the ogr* binaries, that worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

**Background**

Dom's comment solved my issue so I wanted to provide it as an actual answer (in case someone else is following the d3 tutorial).

**Make sure tools are installed correctly**

To do this, type `which ogr2ogr` and `which topojson` on the console.  It should return `/usr/local/bin/ogr2ogr` and `/usr/local/bin/topojson`.

**Move all the files over (yes all of them, not just the .shp file)**

E.g. I moved all the files to my folder '/Users/williamliu/GitHub/d3-examples/maps' and placed the contents of 'ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits' in there.  The relevant files include:

- ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.cpg
- ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.dbf
- ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.prj
- ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
- ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shx

**Run the command**

Navigate to your folder and in the console, run: `ogr2ogr -f geoJSON -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')" subunits.json ne10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp`.  You should now have a new file 'subunits.json' in your folder.

Comment: **Move all the files over (yes all of them, not just the .shp file)** solved my issue. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Yes, "move all the files over" worked perfectly here. The tutorial only told me about the `.shp`, but moving all of them fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10, try to execute this command from any "bash" e.g. `Git Bash`, `MINGW64`, `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` ect. It should help.